# Hack a Sphero so it boots into demo-mode?

Tags: bluetooth, sphero-api, hardware, sphero

Is it possible to reprogram a Sphero by any means, such that it immediately boots up into demo mode when I switch it on?

- PRO: Turning it on takes 1 second; just double-tap the Sphero.
- CON: Starting the Sphero app takes at least 1 minute. Bluetooth pairing from scratch when the app starts generally involves some hoop-jumping.
- PRO: Once the app starts, it takes 1 second (a single button tap) to switch it into demo-mode.
- PRO: The Sphero remains in demo-mode mode autonomously once begun, even if the controlling Bluetooth device is disconnected immediately after activating demo-mode.

It seems metaphysically possible that it could somehow be reprogrammed to boot directly into autonomous demo-mode.

Comment: I appreciate viewer feedback, even if it is down-voting. However, please consider also leaving comments, so we can understand why you believe this to be a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

Sphero's official answer:

> There is not a way to program the Sphero app to open automatically in
>   demo mode.